# fetch data from text file in mvc4 c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to fetch data from text file that is in particular folder into div tag..
MVC is new for me..So explain me briefly..

controller

```
 public ActionResult filexist()
        { 
            string subPath = "~/Content/74/74/6_Hall0/Text/data.txt";
            bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

            if (!exists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
            else
            {

            }
            return View();
        }
```

HTML:

```
   <form action="" method="post">
    <div>
        <textarea rows="3" cols="15" contenteditable="true" name="data"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all,
the default Method in the controller is "GET",
so if you want to use Post so you have to do like this:

in your Controller add "[HttpPost]":

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult filexist()
{
 string subPath = "~/Content/74/74/6_Hall0/Text/data.txt";
 bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));
 if (!exists)
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
 else
   {
   }
 return View();
}
```

and then, in your HTML(View):

```js
@using (Html.BeginForm("filexist", "Your_Controller_Name", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  <div>
    <textarea rows="3" cols="15" contenteditable="true" name="data"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: you can use it with a model or not,
if you want i'll post an example with model...

Comment: public class Shared
    {
        public String getFileData()
        {
            String filename = "~/Content/74/74/6_Hall0/Text/data.txt";
            String Textline = "";
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
            do
            {
                Textline += sr.ReadLine();

            } while (sr.Peek() != -1);
            return Textline;
        }
    } is this correct to fetch data?

Comment: and in controller  public ActionResult filexist()
        {
            String data = "";
            string subPath = "~/Content/74/74/6_Hall0/Text/data.txt";
            bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

            if (!exists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
            else
            {
                Shared s = new Shared();
                data = s.getFileData();
            }
            return View();
        }

Comment: no idea how to display data from controller to that textarea

Comment: give me a second, i''l edit my post.
Do you want to send the file content to the view?

Comment: so yes, you must use model

Comment: yah I gave code of model and controller above is it correct?

Comment: you have to send the model from & to the view...
few more seconds

Comment: in model i have to give virtual path or physical path in filename?

Comment: thnku for ur answer..I have done it!! :) @Tomer Klein

Comment: Mark Tomer answer as an answer. so that people know that your question  has already been answered.